# Issue with @media -sass-debug-info{filename when Grunt creates CSS from SCSS

Tags: css, intellij-idea, sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am using Grunt to watch and compile my CSS from numerous partial SCSS files. So when I update any of my SCSS files the watch generates an updated main.css file. this is okay but I have noticed that all classes seem to be wrapped with the following code, for example

```
@media -sass-debug-info{filename{font-family:file\:\/\/\/Users\/username\/Projects\/my-gitclone\/projectname\/src\/htdocs\/an\/app\/styles\/utilities\/_display\.scss}line{font-family:\0000354}}
.u-body-noscroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I don't understand why the watch is inserting this `@media -sass-debug-info{filename{}line{font-family:\0000XXX}}`, I assumed it may be due to an error in my `_fonts.scss` file but this is fine and the url values are relative:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Merriweather';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('fonts/Merriweather.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('fonts/Merriweather.woff') format('woff'),
  url('fonts/Merriweather.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Merriweather';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url('fonts/MerriweatherBold.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('fonts/MerriweatherBold.woff') format('woff'),
  url('fonts/MerriweatherBold.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

I also thought my _icon-font.scss may be the source of the problem but this is correct? Could the IDE or Grunt be adding this `@media -sass-debug-info`?

I am using Grunt for my watch/task-runner and IntelliJ as my IDE, has anyone came across this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found an answer... in my Grunt file I added `debugInfo: false` to the compass.dist and compass.server tasks.

```
// Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
        compass: {
            options: {
                sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                cssDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
                imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
                importPath: './bower_components',
                httpImagesPath: '/images',
                httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
                httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
                relativeAssets: false,
                assetCacheBuster: false,
                raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated',
                    debugInfo: false
                }
            },
            server: {
                options: {
                    debugInfo: false
                }
            }
        },
```